# Javascript :delete a parent element

Tags: javascript

How can I delete the parent element of a child using an event listener.

I have an html form that when submitted, runs the makeNewBook function and pushes an object containing the form information to an array called myLibrary. It then creates a container div that displays the info from that form, which is placed in a predefined div called shelf(bookshelf). That container also has a delete button in it.

The delete button has an event listener that removes the object from the array, but how can I also remove the container from the page using that last event listener? Thanks

Javasctipt:

```
function makeNewBook() {
    let x = new Book(bookInput.value, authorInput.value, pagesInput.value, readInput.value)   //create a new book using the input vals
    myLibrary.push(x)                                                                         //push the new book object to the books array;
    console.table(myLibrary)


    let container = document.createElement('div')    //create a container for all the info
    container.setAttribute('class', 'container')

    let titlePara = document.createElement('p')
    titlePara.textContent += 'Title: ' + x.title;
    let authorPara = document.createElement('p')
    authorPara.textContent += 'Author: ' + x.author;
    let pagesPara = document.createElement('p')
    pagesPara.textContent += 'Pages: ' + x.pages;
    let readPara = document.createElement('p')
    readPara.textContent += 'Read: ' + x.read


    // delete button
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('input');
    deleteBtn.setAttribute('class','delete')
    deleteBtn.type = 'submit';
    deleteBtn.value = 'Delete'



    // append everyhting to the container div to be put on the shelf
    container.appendChild(titlePara)
    container.appendChild(authorPara)
    container.appendChild(pagesPara)
    container.appendChild(readPara)
    container.appendChild(deleteBtn)
    container.setAttribute('class', `container ${x.title}`)
    shelf.append(container)




    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        let index= myLibrary.indexOf(x); 
        myLibrary.splice(index,1);       //delete that object from the myLibrary array

        document.body.remove(deleteBtn.parentElement)    //This does not work
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `remove` on the node itself

```
deleteBtn.parentElement.remove();
```